# How to "rotate" a wmp object in a windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have to do a hologram projector, but I can't manage to rotate the video in order to have a proper reflection. I know we can't directly rotate a Windows Media Player object in a Windows Form, but I'm wondering how I can do that.

I've been thinking to put the WMP object in a container and just "rotate" it, but I can't manage to find a proper solution.

Comment: WinForms is not the appropriate technology for that kind of things. If you want rotation, then use WPF.

Comment: I am currently trying to use it, just wondered if there was a way to do it with WinForm.